# Only title is not updated in react-chartjs-2 doughnut chart

Tags: reactjs, react-chartjs-2

I am using [react-chartjs-2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chartjs-2) to implement a doughnut chart in my website.

Below is the code I am using to render the chart.

```
const Doughnut = (props) => {
  const { title, labels, colors, projects, percentages, width, height } = props;
  console.log(`title:${title}`); //this logs proper title
  const plugins = [
    {
      beforeDraw: function (chart) {
        console.log(`title:${title}`); //this logs previous title and thus renders previous title
        var width = chart.width,
          height = chart.height,
          ctx = chart.ctx;
        ctx.restore();
        var fontSize = (height / 240).toFixed(2);
        ctx.font = fontSize + "em sans-serif";
        ctx.textBaseline = "top";
        var text = `${title}`,
          textX = Math.round((width - ctx.measureText(text).width) / 2),
          textY = height / 2;
        ctx.fillText(title, textX, textY);
        ctx.save();
      },
    },
  ];

  const data = {
    datasets: [
      {
        data: percentages,
        backgroundColor: colors,
      },
    ],
  };

  return (
    <DoughnutChart
      data={data}
      plugins={plugins}
      width={width}
      height={height}
    />
  );
};
```

I am passing doughnut chart details from my parent component to child component and all props are passed correctly. When I log `props.title` outside beforeDraw function then it logs the proper value but when I log `props.title` inside `beforeDraw` function then it logs the previous value of title and thus it renders the previous value of title.

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

If you're anything like me, you are going to be incredibly annoyed by this answer... But if you set the key prop of your `DoughnutChart` component with something that is unique between the different renders, such as `props.title`, then you should achieve the expected results. I had this same issue and setting the key prop as described resolved it for me.

The intuition behind this solution is that, by setting a key prop that changes, you are telling React to rerender the entire component, including the inner `beforeDataset` callback.

For context, here is a snippet of your code with the modification.

```
const Doughnut = (props) => {
...
...
...
  return (
    <DoughnutChart
      key={props.title}
      data={data}
      plugins={plugins}
      width={width}
      height={height}
    />
  );
};
```